# Optimizing a for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization, for-loop

I am new to JS and have written a for-loop to go over an object and find the lowest number. I have written my if statement two different ways and I was wondering which one would be better for performance and then how do I test the speed to understand how to write code that performs faster.

This data set is naturally very small, but if I had a large set I could see performance mattering.

```
var myObj = {i1: 4, i2: 3, i3: 2};
var myFunc = function (lowest) {
    var newNumber; 
    for (var key in lowest) {
        if (lowest[key] < newNumber) {
            newNumber = lowest[key];
        } else if (newNumber === undefined) {
            newNumber = lowest[key];
        }
    }
    return newNumber;
}
```

//////

```
var myObj = {i1: 4, i2: 3, i3: 2};
var myFunc = function (lowest) {
    var newNumber; 
    for (var key in lowest) {
        if (newNumber === undefined) {
            newNumber = lowest[key]
        } else if (lowest[key] < newNumber) {
            newNumber = lowest[key];;
        }
    }
    return newNumber;
}
```

Comment: Your code (as included here) is a bit baffling. Do you pass `myObj` to `myFunc`? Is `myFunc` intented to find the key of `myObj` that has the lowest corresponding value? Are you *really* asking if changing the order of the if-test will make the loop faster?

Comment: If all of that is the case, the easiest optimisation is to store `lowest[key]` in a temporary variable before doing the if-test. That will reduce 2 object look-ups  (in all but the initial case) to 1.

Comment: Yes, I am passing myObj to myFunc. I am asking if changing the loop will make it faster. Just trying to learn this language and figured that may have an impact on speed at times.

Comment: After that, you need to consider your data. Does the contents of `myObj` change over time? How often is this function called? How big is your real data. If the answers are 'yes', 'often' and 'not so big', then you could consider "memoizing" the result of `myFunc` (goolge it!)

Comment: How did you "find" that it "may have an impact on speed"? Did you do some profiling? or some 'navel gazing'?

Comment: Yes. On average you perform less checks in the first case.

Comment: @thgaskell That assumes branch prediction doesn't work at all -- it probably will though.

Comment: What you already have seems to be a pretty fast way to do this, and more complicated ways aren't neccessarely faster

Comment: I deleted my answer as spurious, it was using a chrome console debugger values() function that is not available in standard javascript.  To do a performance comparison of your code, try http://jsperf.com